# Make changes to `/proc/acpi/wakeup` permanent

Tags: debian, proc, suspend

I disabled most of my entries in `/proc/acpi/wakeup/` to make sure only the power button and the laptop lid can resume my system, not the mouse or keyboard. The problem is: every time I reboot, the settings are reset for some reason.

Is there a way to make these changes permanent? There are some workaround out there that just put the commands into a script hooked to some wakeup routine, but is there really no other solution?

I'm using a Debian/Gnome Windows 10 dual boot laptop

Comment: Can you set it in the bios? Or uefi as it probably is now..

Comment: Nope I checked all my BIOS settings and found nothing helpful there

Comment: old question, but for people looking for a modern solution, you can use systemd-tmpfiles (as explained there : https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/systemd#systemd-tmpfiles_-_temporary_files)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `/proc` is a virtual file system containing [*runtime* system info](https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-automatically-execute-shell-script-at-startup-boot-on-systemd-linux). So its content resets on reboot.

// Edit:
Setup a *udev rule* or create a script `echo`ing the right values to the `/proc/acpi/wakeup/` [on start up](https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-automatically-execute-shell-script-at-startup-boot-on-systemd-linux).

Comment: So, how *exactly* do I set `OHC1` to `disabled` in `/proc/acpi/wakeup`?

Comment: Sorry, @piegames, this seems to require a script triggered on startup (in your case via *systemd*). The script really just needs to `echo` the values to `/proc/acpi/wakeup`. This should give you the idea: https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-automatically-execute-shell-script-at-startup-boot-on-systemd-linux

Comment: The systemd service unit running a script did the job for me. Please update your answer so that it also works without the links.

Comment: Okay it does not work completely: although the script works fine, changes to EHC3 (the one with my mouse on it) does not work when calling the script. I still need to call the command manually as su.

Comment: @piegames If you have to run it as `su`, you can specify exec time user for the service via `User=root`. It should help to resolve an access rights problem.

Comment: `/proc/acpi/wakeup` is not a child of `/proc/sys`, `sysctl` doesn't work here.

Comment: Please update the answer to reflect the @Erik's comment above. Thank you.

Answer (score 24):

For a USB mouse or keyboard, you can use a udev rule to make the setting permanent.  First, look up the PCI vendor ID of your mouse/keyboard using `lsusb`.  For my mouse, it's **046d**:

> Bus 001 Device 006: ID **046d**:c52b Logitech, Inc. Unifying Receiver

Then create a "rules" file like my *`/etc/udev/rules.d/logitech.rules`*, only replace "046d" with the vendor ID of your own device:

```
ACTION=="add", SUBSYSTEM=="usb", DRIVERS=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="046d", ATTR{power/wakeup}="disabled"
```

Comment: I believe this is the correct answer. And it is preferable for modern systems unlike the `/etc/rc.local` solution suggested below.

Comment: It could help to reload the rule: `udevadm control --reload-rules`

Comment: I think you should use `ATTRS{idProduct}=="c52b"` there, too, in case there are more than one product from the same vendor.

Comment: I have [an issue](https://askubuntu.com/q/1373624/21005) with this kind of rule.

Answer (score 5):

The preferred way to do this is by creating a `service` with systemd.
Adding script in `rc.local` is the deprecated way.

1. Create a script file wherever you wish. Ex: `~/scripts/disable-devices-as-wakeup.sh`.

   ```bash
   #!/bin/bash

   declare -a devices=(XHC OCH1 USB1 USB2) # <-- Add your entries here
   for device in "${devices[@]}"; do
       if grep -qw ^$device.*enabled /proc/acpi/wakeup; then
           sudo sh -c "echo $device > /proc/acpi/wakeup"
       fi
   done
   ```
2. Test it by executing it from the terminal.
3. If everything is okay then let's make a service.

   ```shell
   $ touch ~/scripts/disable-devices-as-wakeup.service
   ```

   ~/scripts/disable-devices-as-wakeup.service -

   ```bash
   [Unit]
   Description=Disable devices as wakeup

   [Service]
   ExecStart=/home/username/scripts/disable-devices-as-wakeup.sh
   Type=oneshot

   [Install]
   WantedBy=multi-user.target
   ```
4. Copy or move the service to `/etc/systemd/system/`.

   ```shell
   $ sudo cp ~/scripts/disable-devices-as-wakeup.service /etc/systemd/system/
   ```
5. Enable the service.

   ```shell
   $ systemctl enable disable-devices-as-wakeup.service
   ```
6. Restart the OS and check the status.

   ```shell
   $ systemctl status disable-devices-as-wakeup.service
   ```

Detailed explanation found [here](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/7/html/system_administrators_guide/chap-managing_services_with_systemd).

Comment: If you have a SELinux enabled distro (like fedora) be sure to

1. create the Service directly under `/etc/systemd/system/` and not copy it there
2. create the script not under your home directory, but i.e. under `/usr/local/bin/`

Otherwise you will have problems with the SELinux context. Either Systemd will not find your service file or it won't execute the script because Systemd isn't permitted to execute files lying in home directories.

Answer (score 2):

[acpitool](https://packages.debian.org/stretch/acpitool) can be used for this `apt install acpitool`

And then

```
sudo acpitool -W [some number]
```

where `some number` is device id from `/proc/acpi/wakeup`

```
maciej@michal:~$ sudo acpitool -W 22
  Changed status for wakeup device #22 (UHC6)

   Device   S-state   Status   Sysfs node
  ---------------------------------------
  1. PCE2     S4    *disabled  pci:0000:00:02.0
  2. PCE3     S4    *disabled
  3. PCE4     S4    *disabled  pci:0000:00:04.0
  4. RLAN     S4    *enabled   pci:0000:02:00.0
  5. PCE5     S4    *disabled
  6. PCE6     S4    *disabled
  7. PCE7     S4    *disabled  pci:0000:00:07.0
  8. PCE9     S4    *disabled
  9. PCEA     S4    *disabled
  10. PCEB    S4    *disabled
  11. PCEC    S4    *disabled
  12. SBAZ    S4    *disabled  pci:0000:00:14.2
  13. PS2K    S4    *disabled
  14. PS2M    S4    *disabled
  15. UAR1    S4    *disabled  pnp:00:03
  16. P0PC    S4    *disabled  pci:0000:00:14.4
  17. UHC1    S4    *disabled  pci:0000:00:12.0
  18. UHC2    S4    *disabled  pci:0000:00:12.1
  19. UHC3    S4    *disabled  pci:0000:00:12.2
  20. USB4    S4    *disabled  pci:0000:00:13.0
  21. UHC5    S4    *disabled  pci:0000:00:13.1
  22. UHC6    S4    *disabled  pci:0000:00:13.2
  23. UHC7    S4    *enabled   pci:0000:00:14.5
```

Comment: It was asked for a permanent solution. This one is only temporary.

Answer (score 1):

[Eric Garrido](http://ericgar.com/2009/07/08/how-to-resume-from-suspend-by-keystroke-in-linux/) has a script in `/etc/rc.local` that echo's those devices that are allowed to wake up his system, to `/proc/acpi/wakeup`.

```bsh
for i in `/bin/grep USB /proc/acpi/wakeup | /usr/bin/awk '{print $1}'`; 
do 
    echo $i > /proc/acpi/wakeup; 
done
```

Comment: The `/etc/rc.local` is much shorter!

Comment: @JeremyBoden, much shorter than ... ?

Comment: ;) Much shorter than a set of Systemd scripts. I wrote one set of 3 to run a single command weekly [fstrim] but I would have to look at the man pages and run some find commands if I wanted to modify anything. Why can't Systemd put everything in /etc? I've got stuff in /etc, /home, /usr and /var!

Comment: @JeremyBoden don't ask me, I wouldn't touch systemd with a stick.

Answer (score 1):

I decided to create script in */usr/lib/systemd/system-sleep/*

according to [man page](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd-suspend.service.html) **systemd** will run it just before suspend.

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to get away with a crontab on reboot if the entry only reverses on reboot.

On startup, the following crontab will reverse the entry XHC.

`@reboot /bin/sh -c '/bin/echo XHC > /proc/acpi/wakeup'`

Answer (score 0):

The script file in [Hrishikesh Kadam's answer](/a/634595/112566) is good, but rather than incorporating it in a service, I dropped it in a directory that is run by the system as it is entering suspend mode, so the updates to `/proc/apci/wakeup` are fresh as the system is going into suspend mode and a service isn't necessary.
In my case, I named the file `disable-some-wake`. The format of the file is:

```bash
#! /bin/bash
case $1 in
    pre)
        declare -a devices=(RP09 PXSX) # <-- Add your entries here

        for device in "${devices[@]}"; do
            if $(grep -qw ^${device}.*enabled /proc/acpi/wakeup); then
                echo ${device} > /proc/acpi/wakeup
            fi
        done
    ;;
esac
```

The `pre` case specifies that this is pre-suspend. Now drop it into the directory:

```bash
sudo cp disable-some-wake /usr/lib/systemd/system-sleep
```

and change the permissions:

```bash
sudo chmod 755 /usr/lib/systemd/system-sleep/disable-some-wake
```

That’s it. No need to start a service or reboot your system.

Answer (score 0):

```
# cat /etc/systemd/system/acpi-wake.service 
[Unit]
Description=ACPI Wake Service
Before=sleep.target

[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/bin/sh -c "for i in $(cat /proc/acpi/wakeup| grep enabled| awk '{print $1}'| xargs); do [ $i != PBTN ] && echo $i| tee /proc/acpi/wakeup; done"

[Install]
WantedBy=sleep.target

# ln -s /etc/systemd/system/acpi-wake.service  /etc/systemd/system/sleep.target.wants/acpi-wake.service

# systemctl daemon-reload
```

Answer (score 0):

The `systemd` way:

Create `/etc/tmpfiles.d/disable-bluetooth-wake-from-sleep.conf`:

```
#    Path                  Mode UID  GID  Age Argument
w+   /proc/acpi/wakeup     -    -    -    -   OCH1
w+   /proc/acpi/wakeup     -    -    -    -   XHCI

# It is possible to write multiple lines to the same file, either with \n in the argument
# or using the w+ type on multiple lines (including the first one) for appending
```

Apply the changes without reboot:

```
sudo systemd-tmpfiles --create
```