# Cannot prevent Rii keyboard from waking PC, I can prevent Coolermaster from waking PC

Tags: ubuntu

I have two keyboards.

1. For the Coolermaster I can prevent the keyboard from waking the PC from sleep by adding a udev rule.
2. For the Rii RK908 I cannot get the same change to work and I've no idea why.
3. I've used the Coolermaster for years, the Rii is a new keyboard.
4. Ubuntu 22.04 LTS
5. The udev rules have the same file permissions.
6. The issue doesn't appear to be the USB ports as I swap the keyboards between the same port.
7. I've tried different USB ports and experience the same issues.

**Coolermaster Strom QuickFire Rapid**

lsusb gives: Bus 002 Device 005: ID 2516:0004 Cooler Master Co., Ltd. Storm QuickFire Rapid Mechanical Keyboard

udev rule is: ACTION=="add", SUBSYSTEM=="usb", DRIVERS=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="2516", ATTR{power/wakeup}="disabled"

**Rii RK908**

lsusb gives: Bus 002 Device 004: ID 1a2c:99f4 China Resource Semico Co., Ltd USB Gaming Keyboard

udev rule is: ACTION=="add", SUBSYSTEM=="usb", DRIVERS=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="1a2c", ATTR{power/wakeup}="disabled"

**Underlying Issue**
The underlying issue I'm trying to solve is after putting the PC to sleep, if I have the Rii keyboard plugged in then it automatically wakes the PC after an amount of time, say 30 minutes.  I've never had this issue with the Coolermaster.

So I want to do one of the following:

1. Allow the Rii keyboard to wake the PC but only when I press a key.
2. Prevent the Rii keyboard from waking the PC when even if I press a key i.e. I have to use the power button.

Am I doing anything wrong, what else can I try please ?

References:
Using a udev rule came from: [Make changes to `/proc/acpi/wakeup` permanent](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/417956/make-changes-to-proc-acpi-wakeup-permanent/532839#532839)

Edit: I've added the output from
*more /proc/acpi/wakeup* after the keyboard has been plugged in.  The output is identical for both keyboards (only 1 keyboard is plugged in at once). Device    S-state   Status   Sysfs node

PS2K      S3    *disabled

PS2M      S3    *disabled

P0P1      S4    *disabled

USB1      S3    *disabled

USB2      S3    *disabled

USB3      S3    *disabled

USB4      S3    *disabled

USB5      S3    *disabled

USB6      S3    *disabled

USB7      S3    *disabled

RP01      S4    *disabled  pci:0000:00:1c.0

PXSX      S4    *disabled

RP02      S4    *disabled

PXSX      S4    *disabled

RP03      S4    *disabled  pci:0000:00:1c.2

PXSX      S4    *enabled   pci:0000:03:00.0

RP04      S4    *disabled

PXSX      S4    *disabled

RP05      S4    *disabled  pci:0000:00:1c.4

PXSX      S4    *disabled  pci:0000:04:00.0

RP06      S4    *disabled

PXSX      S4    *disabled

RP07      S4    *disabled

PXSX      S4    *disabled

RP08      S4    *disabled

PXSX      S4    *disabled

PEG0      S4    *disabled  pci:0000:00:01.0

PEGP      S4    *disabled

PEG1      S4    *disabled

PEG2      S4    *disabled

PEG3      S4    *disabled

GLAN      S4    *disabled

EHC1      S4    *enabled   pci:0000:00:1d.0

EHC2      S4    *enabled   pci:0000:00:1a.0

XHC   S4    *disabled

HDEF      S4    *disabled  pci:0000:00:1b.0

PWRB      S3    *enabled   platform:PNP0C0C:00

Comment: Hm, that wakeup functionality is not a feature of your keyboard, nor really of the operating system (as that's not running before getting woken up), it's functionality of the ACPI controller that can be programmed to ignore some sources of wakeup. That makes it surprising this is USB device-specific!

Comment: Can you add the content of /proc/acpi/wakeup after the Rii keyboard has been plugged in, and before? might be sufficient to look at the `EHC`, `UHC`, `OHC` lines

Comment: Marcus: I've added the output of /proc/acpi/wakeup

Comment: Marcus: Thanks for the tip about /proc/acpi/wakeup.  After some Googling I've disabled ECH1 and the PC no longer wakes when I press a key on the keyboard. 

I need to test this definitely doesn't randomly wake up my PC by leaving it overnight, then I need to make this a permanent change.  I appreciate your comment as it's help me make progress.

Comment: Hope it works out, Phil! If it does, don't forget to leave what you did here as answer to your own question – that's highly encouraged!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was the acpi controller and the solution was to disable EHC1, as suggested in the comments by Marcus Müller. Thank you very much for helping.

In /proc/acpi/wakeup EHC1 was originally enabled: EHC1 S4 *enabled pci:0000:00:1d.0

I toggled this from enabled to disabled using *echo EHC1 | sudo tee /proc/acpi/wakeup*

When I left the PC in sleep mode overnight, it was still in sleep mode the next morning, which solves my issue.